# In VS Code REST CLIENT plugin - how do you store variables from data retrieved from a request?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

I'm trying to do something simple:

```
post http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
    "username": "name",
    "password" : "password" 
}
```

This sends me an authorisation token which I want to use in future calls.

I understand how to update .vscode/settings.json to store environment variables but I want to store the auth token I've just received.

Answer (score 15):

Ok so you reference a previous API call. Documentation is ... limited.  If anyone has thoughts on long-time storage of the token so calls aren't made constantly, that would be great.

```
### login
# @name postLogin
post http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
    "username": "name",
    "password" : "password" 
}

@token = {{postLogin.response.body.apptoken}}

### Get Profile details
get {{hostname}}/profile
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
```

Comment: Does this still work? I get an error on the `@token = ...` line. REST Client thinks it is continuation of the JSON body of the POST request

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example that works.

```
@host = http://localhost:3001/api/v1
@user_email = test@gmail.com
@user_password = 12345678

### Login
# @name login

POST {{ host }}/auth
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "{{ user_email}}",
  "password": "{{ user_password }}"
}

### Get me
@access_token = {{login.response.body.access_token}}

GET {{host}}/user/me
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{ access_token }}
```